# MySql error System.InvalidOperationException in windows application-c#

Tags: c#, mysql, windows, cmd

I am getting the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in MySql.Data.CF.dll

in my windows application program.

**Below is my code.**

```
In app.config:

inside connectionStrings tag

add name="ConnectionString"     
connectionString="server=localhost;database=my_db;user=root;port=3306;
password=mypwd;

In LoginForms.cs 

using System.Configuration; 
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient; 

namespace MySoftware 
{ 
public partial class Login : Form 
{ 
MySqlConnection conn; 
public static int valid = 0; 
public Login() 
{ 
InitializeComponent(); 
} 

private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
var connectionString =   
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString; 
conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString); 
conn.open(); 
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();  
cmd.CommandText = "Verify_Login"; 
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", textBox1.Text); 
cmd.Parameters["@uname"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input; 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", textBox2.Text); 
cmd.Parameters["@pwd"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input; 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@result", MySqlDbType.Int32); 
cmd.Parameters["@result"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // At this line the error is thrown
int valid = (int)(cmd.Parameters["@result"].Value); 
} 
} 
} 

Verify_Login is a stored procedure which is created in MySQL as below. 

CREATE PROCEDURE `Verify_Login`(in uname varchar(20),in pwd varchar(20),out    
result bool) 
BEGIN 
select count(*) into result from Login where uname=uname and password=pwd; 
END 

Could anyone please help me with this?
```

Comment: Are you developing for Windows Phone/Mobile?

Comment: Nope, just a windows form application.

Comment: If i am not mistaken MySql.Data.CF.dll is for the .NET Compact Framework, which -- if i remember correctly -- is only useful for Windows Phone/Mobile projects. Try using MySql.Data.dll instead (and remove MySql.Data.CF.dll from your project references)

Comment: I tried that too. But it doesn't seem working.

Comment: The exception message reported is not alone. There is another one in the InnerException field. And I bet that has something to say about a command without an open connection to use....

Comment: yes, but I have a code to open connection 'con.Open()'.What shall you suggest to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code fails because is trying to execute a command and this command is not bound to an open connection. You have a lot of ways to bind the connection

```
MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
```

or

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlText, conn);
```

or

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
```

Of course the suggestion to use the appropriate Connector for your environment still stands....

Your code refactored a bit

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
     var connectionString =   
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString; 
     using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString)) 
     using(MySqlCommand cmd = new conn.CreateCommand())
     {
          conn.open(); 
          cmd.CommandText = "Verify_Login"; 
          cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
          .....
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
          int valid = (int)(cmd.Parameters["@result"].Value); 
     } 
}
```

Comment: That is correct, it worked perfectly when I added 'cmd.Connection = conn'.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Steve. Thumbs Up!